# Controlling the placement of the paginator

Tags: java, pagination, displaytag

According to the docs, Displaytag can be configured to put a paginator before or after the generated table element via the `paging.banner.placement` property.

However, I would like to place the paginator in it's own row in the table footer.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this within the Displaytag Framework?

The only solution that I can see so far, is to let Displaytag generate a paginator as usual and then use JavaScript to move the paginator into a new row in the table footer.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you wish to do this - typically, tables are wrapped within a div so that when the display tag executes the banner is contained with the same width as the table and it ends up looking pretty nice anyways.  Something like <div style="width:100%"> <display:table ... /> </div>

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the default banners, you'll see that *spans* are used.
In order to give a banner its own row in the footer, you should use *divs* or tables. and rows

See here for more on the default banner content - http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/configuration.html